# Apparent php parse error - You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting

Tags: php

I am moving up from php 5.2 to 5.4 and am getting the `You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting` error. Yes I *know* about `date_default_timezone_set('zone_name')`, setting the timezone in my php.ini and using gmdate(), just hear me out... :-)

So the error comes out complete with a line number plus a second error:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getHostname()`

This is where it gets interesting. The line numbers given for the date.timezone setting and for the redeclaration error are the same and the actual line quoted is: `return $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` and forms a part of a small wrapper function:

```
function getHostname()
{
return $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; # This is the line the parse identifies
}
```

If I comment out the function the parser is happy, or if I move the function in the code file, then the line number the parser complains about stays on the moved `return $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` line, so it is consistent in what it is complaining about.

However, while the parser is consistent, the line is is complaining about is nothing to do with the date.timezone setting, nor is this function redeclared and adding `date_default_timezone_set('zone_name')` to the function makes no difference...even if there was a link between timezone and hostname.

I've checked the codebase and the `getHostname` function is only declared in one place plus this code has been running for years under php 5.2 and lower without any redeclaration problems.

Now I could solve the problem by dropping the use of the wrapper function and just use bare `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, but I am intrigued by what looks like the parser getting confused.

Comment: I bet it has something to do with : http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

Comment: Ah...from 5.3 upwards! Basically a built in wrapper to do what I was doing and explains all as I'm trying to redeclare a native function. Odd though about the date.time error. Suggests I can happily drop my function and just ensure capitalisation doens't catch me out.